# Javascript For/in loop not working - Object property is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, function, object, error-handling, for-in-loop

So i'm working on a simple For/in loop exercise from a course i am  taking.
We have a simple object with 3 properties and we have to create a function that takes 2 parameters - the object name and the item you're looking for.

I made my function and compared to the solution from the teacher and it's exactly the same. The problem is when i try it out in the console, i get an error that accuses the object property is not defined.

The code is as follows:

```js
// Question #2:
// Write a function checkBasket() that lets you know if the item is in the basket or not
const amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for(item in basket) {
    console.log(item);
     if(item === lookingFor) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
    }     
   }
   return `${lookingfor} is not in your basket`;
}
```

Would really appreciate any help guys! It's been a tough but enjoyable learning process!

Thanks!

Comment: You have to call the function!

Comment: you have a undefined variable `lookingfor` in you last return you need `lookingFor`

Comment: Hey guys, appreciate the input, but the problem was that when i was calling the function, i was not writing the item between quotes! :P Silly mistake, but the lecture really got us confuse with this exercise hehe thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as expected for me, so the issue is probably with how you call the function or something in code not shown.

PS: If you use an array instead of an object to store the items, you can use array.find() or array.indexOf() and such to make manipulating the basket easier.

```js
// Question #2:
// Write a function checkBasket() that lets you know if the item is in the basket or not
const amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for(item in basket) {
    console.log(item);
     if(item === lookingFor) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
    }     
   }
   return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
}

console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'floss' ));
console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'books' ));
console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'glasses' ));
```

```js
const amazonBasket = [
  { "order_id": 1, "product_id": 13341544, "product_name": "glasses", "quantity": 1 },
  { "order_id": 1, "product_id": 12121321, "product_name": "books", "quantity": 5 },
  { "order_id": 1, "product_id": 47254114, "product_name": "floss", "quantity": 100 }
];

const checkBasket = ( basket, lookingFor ) => {
  const item = basket.find( item => item.product_name === lookingFor );
  if ( item ) return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
  else return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
};

console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'floss' ));
console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'books' ));
console.log( checkBasket( amazonBasket, 'glasses' ));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! Your code/test made me realize i made the stupid mistake of not including quotation marks around the `lookingFor` item when calling the function :P Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code have a typo in last line: lookingfor instead of lookingFor

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, Alexey! Turns out the problem was also calling the function. I was not including the `lookingFor` item into quotation marks when calling the function! :P

Answer (score 0):

Just got to this section of the course. The object should be a string. Try it this way, after putting the code, call the function like this:

```
checkBasket(amazonBasket, 'books')
```